# JSon Scheme element definition Query

Tags: json, jsonschema

The following two elements ( system and doc_type ) are example elements defined in my JSon schema that was generated using Jsonix

How can these definitions be updated to specify 
min and max value effectively if this a mandatory element.

Also for numeric, how can i define the min and max values the element can have eg range of 4 to 10.

Thank you for your help

Pete

```
"system":{
                    "title":"system",
                    "allOf":[
                        {
                            "$ref":"http://www.jsonix.org/jsonschemas/w3c/2001/XMLSchema.jsonschema#/definitions/string"
                        }
                    ],
                    "propertyType":"element",
                    "elementName":{
                        "localPart":"system",
                        "namespaceURI":""
                    }
                },

"docType":{
                    "title":"docType",
                    "allOf":[
                        {
                            "$ref":"http://www.jsonix.org/jsonschemas/w3c/2001/XMLSchema.jsonschema#/definitions/short"
                        }
                    ],
                    "propertyType":"element",
                    "elementName":{
                        "localPart":"doc_type",
                        "namespaceURI":""
                    }
                },
```

Comment: Although there appears to be some JSON Schema keywords here, there are also a number of non JSON Schema keywords, so it looks like the behaviour is unique to the library. You would need to check what the library in question supports.

Comment: Oh that is interesting. Does this mean the generated schema is non standard ?

Comment: `propertyType` and `elementName` are not JSON Schema keywords. The use of `allOf` and `$ref` is fine though. I would guess the library is using the additional keywords to do something extra, but I don't have the time to confirm that. Additional keywords are allowed, but ignored by default by standard implementations.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so quickly .. much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to join our slack community found on the website. Also feel free to check out my profile here for other links.